# Meta Recruiting SQL -- Join Part 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have done my best to neatly format the meta recruiting question below. My current query that I'm trying to ascertain the ratio is this. Returning correct 2/3 values but the ratio is returning as all 1's. Any help on where I'm going wrong?

Update:

```
SELECT product_family,
SUM(units_sold) as total_units_sold,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id IS NOT 0 then units_sold ELSE 0 END) as units_sold_with_promo,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id IS 0 then units_sold ELSE 0 END) as units_sold_without_promo,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id IS NOT 0 then units_sold ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id IS 0 THEN units_sold ELSE 0 END)as float)  as TEST_B
FROM products p
JOIN product_classes c ON c.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY product_family;
```

this is returning

[image]

Edit:
After querying

```
SELECT product_family, units_sold, promotion_id FROM products p
 JOIN product_classes c ON c.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
 JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id;
```

This is the snapshot. I can't share the data because I don't have it other than what I'm querying.

[image]

BACKGROUND:

The following schema is a subset of a relational database of a grocery store
chain. This chain sells many products of different product classes to its
customers across its different stores. It also conducts many different
promotion campaigns.

The relationship between the four tables we want to analyze is depicted below:

[image]

### PROMPT:

- The CMO is interested in understanding how the sales of different
- product families are affected by promotional campaigns.
- To do so, for each of the available product families,
- show the total number of units sold,
- as well as the ratio of units sold that had a valid promotion
- to units sold without a promotion,
  -- ordered by increasing order of total units sold.

[image]

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN pro.promotion_id IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END)` counts the non-null values. I.e. the same as `COUNT(pro.promotion_id)`.

Comment: Thanks @jarih, that doesn't really get me to the correct ratio still though. 

Also why would someone downvote this?

Comment: Don't know. (I didn't.)

Comment: But you could add sample table data and the matching expected result as formatted text (images make copy-and-paste impossible.) I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_family,
SUM(units_sold) as total_units_sold,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id IS NOT 0 then units_sold * 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / 
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id = 0 THEN units_sold * 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as NUMERIC) as ratio_units_sold_with_promo_to_sold_without_promo
FROM products p
JOIN product_classes c ON c.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY product_family
ORDER BY total_units_sold ASC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feels like what you're looking for (I added an extra column for clarity):

```
SELECT product_family,
      SUM(units_sold) as total_units_sold,
      SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id > 0 then units_sold ELSE 0 END) as sold_when_promoted,
      SUM(CASE WHEN s.promotion_id > 0 then units_sold ELSE 0 END)::numeric /
        SUM(units_sold) AS ratio_units_sold_with_promo_to_sold_without_promo
FROM products p
JOIN product_classes c ON c.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY product_family;
```

... or using a filter clause ...

```
SELECT product_family,
      SUM(units_sold) as total_units_sold,
      SUM(units_sold) filter(where s.promotion_id > 0) as sold_when_promoted,
      SUM(units_sold) filter(where s.promotion_id > 0)::numeric /
        SUM(units_sold) AS ratio_units_sold_with_promo_to_sold_without_promo
FROM products p
JOIN product_classes c ON c.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY product_family;
```

I don't think you need to guard against division by zero, but if you had a sum of sales of zer for a product you'd need to handle that.

Edit: I think you don't need to reference the promotions table, actually.

Comment: This is returning total_units_sold and sold_when_promoted as 1:1

Comment: But you do appear to be right about not having to reference promotions. That's helpful, the promotion_id in sales will just be a 0

Comment: Is that in the current version without the join to the promotions table?

Comment: Yep. I updated my approach based on your advice but still returning a 0 at the ratio.

Comment: Oh, does s.promotion_id = 0 mean "no promotion"?

Comment: It does seem that way. Yes. Updated a query above to reflect some sample data.

Comment: OK, maybe the current version then - check if promotion_id > 0 instead of is not null?

Comment: Divide return still returning zero... i'm clueless

Comment: Oh, duh. It's integer division ... see latest, with `::numeric`

Comment: Should the divisor have a `filter(where s.promotion_id = 0)`?

Comment: Of course it's not allowing the ::numeric cast.... I think this thing is buggy

Comment: is there an error message? Yeah, maybe filter on the divisor if you need that logic.

Comment: unrecognized token ":"

Comment: OH...... Note that in this editor, you are using a SQLite database. In the interview you will run the queries against a PostgreSQL database. Yet knowing standard ANSI SQL is sufficient for the interview.

Comment: Oof. Whatever the SQLite version of that is I guess! 

Answer (score 0):

```
select   avg(case when is_low_fat_flg=1 and is_recyclable_flg=1 then 1 else 0 end)*100  as pct_low_fat_and_recyclable
    from products
```

Comment: What does this code do and how does it solve OP's problem? Code blocks with no description or explanation are rarely useful for readers. Also, Stack Snippets should be reserved for runnable code, which means HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript.